# Position of title

Tags: titles

I have this chunk of code for the title page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{Today}
\maketitle
```

I want to position My Title more above on the page. How do I possible achieve this?

Comment: That code won't make a page, title or otherwise. Please can you make it compilable? By default, `article`s do not have title pages at all. Are you using `titlepage` or do you just have a title? I guess you want the title to be higher on the page? Have you looked at the `titling` package?

Comment: @cfr Sorry I forgot writing \maketitle

Comment: @JunJang... Please always test your examples to be sure they are working examples (you miss `begin` and `end` document)

Comment: And you need a `document` environment. So you are not using a title page but you want less vertical space before the title, is that it? And you're using the standard layout? Are you happy with the default margins? Because, if not, I'd start by loading `geometry` and setting the margins. Then adjust the title relative to those if you still want to move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by seeing where the title is right now. Completing the example and adding `geometry` with `pass, showframe`, we can see the defaults:

[image: default title on page]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{Today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want to fiddle with the margins, do this before adjusting the title. For example, if we drop the `pass`, we'll get `geometry`'s defaults:

[image: <code>geometry</code>'s defaults]

This itself has the effect of reducing the vertical space before the title, because the new top margin is smaller than LaTeX's default.

But you might, of course, want a still smaller margin. If so, adjust that before considering the title.

Adding

```
\geometry{top=20mm}
```

we get

[image: title with top margin of 20mm]

If, when you've sorted the page layout, you'd still like to adjust the title position, consider loading the `titling` package.

The default uses a `center` environment for the title, so let's try just using `\centering` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\geometry{top=20mm}
\pretitle{\begingroup\centering\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\endgroup}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{Today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: title going up]

Obviously, the document is now quite unbalanced: if you change `top`, you will want to change the other margins, too. Tweak as required.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `geometry` is the right tool for this, because you want to move up *an element* of the first page, rather than changing the page layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip 2em}{\vspace*{-3cm}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{Today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Adjust `-3cm` to a value that suits you.

[image]